# Issue with API pagination in django

Tags: html, django

the problem I'm having is that when I try to click next in the pagination that I did, the link param name "dataType" dosen't stays and it resets to none value, please help. I'm Using django

I did some debug and appears like this:

```
[13/Jan/2024 13:33:57] "GET /search/?query=Spaghetti&dataType=&page=27 HTTP/1.1" 200 9901
query: Spaghetti, dataType: Branded, page: 1
[13/Jan/2024 13:34:06] "GET /search/?query=Spaghetti&dataType=Branded HTTP/1.1" 200 7304
query: Spaghetti, dataType: , page: 2
```

And this is my html:

```
<!-- PAGINATION LINKS -->
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if pagination.current_page > 1 %}
        <a href="{% url 'search_aliment' %}?query={{query}}&dataType={{dataType}}&page=1">&laquo; first</a>
        <a href="{% url 'search_aliment' %}?query={{query}}&dataType={{dataType}}&page={{ pagination.current_page|add:'-1' }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            Page {{pagination.current_page}} of {{pagination.total_pages}}.
        </span>
        {% if pagination.current_page < pagination.total_pages %}
        <a href="{% url 'search_aliment' %}?query={{query}}&dataType={{dataType}}&page={{ pagination.current_page|add:'1' }}">next</a>
        <a href="{% url 'search_aliment' %}?query={{query}}&dataType={{dataType}}&page={{pagination.total_pages}}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

I don't know if the issue is from the views.py or the html or the forms.py, apreciate your responses!!!

I have tried changing the links in the html and nothind I did worked.